# 9 patch drawable for a clickable view

Tags: android, nine-patch

I want to use a 9-patch drawable to use as the background of layout which I set to be clickable

the drawable I use is actually a selector xml which I wrote like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/action_item_pressed" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/action_item" />
</selector>
```

and my layout is like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:background="@drawable/action_item_btn">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/icon" 
    android:layout_width="30dp" 
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:src="@drawable/sword_item"
    android:scaleType="centerInside"/>

<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/progress"
    android:layout_width="35dp"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Horizontal"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

the problem is that the `action_item drawable` is not showing and `action_item_pressed drawable` is showing when pressing on the view.

any thoughts?

does the way I inflate this view, can cause this?

BTW: in the eclipse graphical layout, it is showing and if I add the view when the application is running, it works.

here's the way I inflate this view (it calls from the `onCreate` method):

```
int achievementsNumber = AchievementsManager.ACTIVE_ACHIEVEMENTS_COUNT;
    m_achievementsLayout = new LinearLayout(m_context.getApplicationContext());
    m_achievementsLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    m_achievementsLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)m_context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    for(int i=0; i < achievementsNumber; i++){
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.achievement_item, m_achievementsLayout, true);
    }

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_VERTICAL);
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
    addView(m_achievementsLayout, params);
```

Comment: I know. and I know the 9-patch itself is not the problem (unless 9-patches sometimes work and sometimes they don't

Comment: And if you change the drawables in their places? Which one appears?

Comment: Yes. Just to check if it's a problem with drawable or with the xml file

Comment: mmm.. the `action_item_pressed` is shown and the action_item is not. but the thing is, I use this drawable in other view, and it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well it seems that inflating this view and adding it to the layout on the `onCreate` of the activity is a problem and caused this issue.

I moved the inflating and added the view after the onResume and it works.

I guess the reason is that the `ViewGroup` I'm adding the inflated view to, doesn't have a size yet.